# Use only a domain and disable https://storage.googleapis.com url access

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am newbie at cloud servers and I've opened a google cloud storage to host image files. I've verified my domain and configured it, to view images via my domain. The problem is, same file is both accessible via my domain ***example.com/images/tiny.png*** and also via ***storage.googleapis.com/example.com/images/tiny.png*** Is there any solution to *disable access via storage.googleapis.com* and use only my domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Google Cloud Platform Support Version:**

**NOTE: This is the reply from Google Cloud Platform Support when contacted via email...**

I understand that you have set up a domain name for one of your Cloud Storage buckets and you want to make sure only URLs starting with your domain name have access to this bucket.

I am afraid that this is not possible because of how Cloud Storage permission works.

Making a Cloud Storage bucket publicly readable also gives each of its files a public link. And currently this public link can’t be disabled.

A workaround would be implement a proxy program and running it on a Compute Engine virtual machine. This VM will need a static external IP so that you can map your domain to it. The proxy program will be in charged of returning the requested file from a predefined Cloud Storage bucket while the bucket keeps to be inaccessible to the public.

You may find these documents helpful if you are interested in this workaround:
1. Quick start to set up a Linux VM (1).
2. Python API for accessing Cloud Storage files (2).
3. How to download service account keys to grant a program access to a set of services (3).
4. Pricing calculator for getting a picture on how much a VM may cost (4).

[(1) https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-linux](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-linux)
[(2) https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/)
[(3) https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys)
[(4) https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/)

**My Version:**

It seems the solution to this question is really a simple, just FUSE Google Cloud Storage with VM Instance.

After FUSE private files from GCS can be accessed through VM's IP address. It made Google Cloud Storage Bucket act like a directory.

The detailed documentation about how to setup FUSE in Google Cloud is [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse).

Comment: Not sure your exact use case, but if performance is a concern, there are downsides to this approach. You're adding a single point of failure and a regional dependency in front of GCS if you use a VM to proxy. GCS has some built in caching that can act as a CDN for public objects, so you'll give this up with a VM. In your case, what is the harm that your image is available via 2 different URLs? All public objects in GCS actually have a few ways to access them already, but it typically does no harm.

Comment: @jon_wu
Main reason for avoiding GCS URL is **to avoid hot-linking**.
I agree that sometimes Fuse gets issues like unmounted bucket from VM,...
To avoid that one such case, I use crontab
`* * * * * cd /var/www/ && gcsfuse -o allow_other [MY GCS Bucket] /var/www/html/`
For CDN part, I'm very much satisfied with full featured **Cloudflare**. And also you'll get bonus **Apache/Nginx** control when serving files through VM from GCS.

Comment: sounds like a good way to go! If you have Cloudflare in front, that definitely works for the caching part. However, vanilla Cloudflare caching may have limitations if you want to limit hotlinking in the sense of not letting people embed your images. They don't support the `vary` header outside of `accept-encoding`, which means you couldn't say cache an image for people who aren't hotlinking, but serve something else to people who are (based on the referer header). If you wanted to use Cloudflare and go serverless and have more logic like this, you could use Cloudflare Workers too.